# Using CMD+Tab two switch between applications focuses the wrong window in the selected application

Tags: keyboard, big-sur, application-switcher

Say I’m in Chrome and I have three Chrome windows open. Window #2 is focused. I <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>  to Apple Mail (or any other open program), then <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> back to Chrome and Window #1 is now focused. This happens every single time, and in every application with multiple windows.

I’m using Big Sur v11.1.

Comment: Are all the Chrome windows in the same Space?

Comment: They are in the same space.

Answer (score 0):

This Apple support [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252399809) says that Big Sur 11.2 fixes the problem.

Comment: Monterey 12.6, the bug is still present.. not fixed :(